# Cannot open MapInfo created .TAB files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo, tab

Newly installed QGIS and trying to open a .TAB file created with MapInfo Pro but fails to create shapefile receiving message ".TAB file not supported".

I Followed instructions > layers > add vector layer >.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try drag and drop the `.TAB` file onto the map window. If the map appears, right-click on the layer list and `Save As` as ESRI shapefile (.shp).

Comment: This YouTube video shows step by step to deal with your issue, How to open MapInfo .map file in QGIS and export them to .shp

Comment: Does the tab file open successfully in MapInfo?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the table is an Extended MapInfo Table build with a 64 bit version of MapInfo Pro?

Open the tab file in a text editor and see if it says "Type NATIVE" or "Type NATIVEX"

NATIVEX is the new Extended MapInfo Table format which isn't supported by the MITAB driver and so not supported by QGIS.

You can try to save it into a "standard" MapInfo Table using MapInfo Pro.

Comment: There seems to have been a solution to this on the MapInfo side of things: http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP06_KnowledgeWithSidebarTroubleshoot?id=kA2800000004MjxCAE&popup=false&lang=en_US However, the vital piece of info to fix it is missing. Anyone have any ideas on how to adjust the preferences.xml MapInfo file to the QGIS friendly version? Or how to edit associated files with the tab file?

Comment: @Ian, check the article again. I have asked for missing piece to get added to the article

Comment: the article is now updated, thanks for getting this sorted.

Comment: This is the answer. But it looks like MapInfo files are no longer compatible with QGIS...

Comment: For now, it's only the "new" Extended MapInfo tables, also known as NativeX, that aren't supported in QGIS. If you create the older Native Tab Files you should be able to use this in QGIS